# Why do I get Run-time Error 58 - File already exists while copying files in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy files in VBA using this code

```
Sub move_data()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet:

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

FromPath = FSO.GetFolder(ws.Range("E1").Value)
ToPath = FSO.GetFolder(ws.Range("E3").Value)

For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath
Next FileInFromFolder

End Sub
```

I am getting

> Run-time Error 58 - File already exists

although there are no files in the `ToPath`

If I reference the folders directly instead of referencing the folder names in cells E1 and E3 of Sheet1 the code works.

Comment: So if you hardcode the values in `FromPath` and `ToPath` it works? Have you checked the values stored in the range? Possibly a worksheet reference issue although you explicitly declared so not likely. I would `Debug.Print ws.Range("E1").Value` etc just to check while stepping through the code

Comment: Clarification: I am trying to move files of course, not to copy them

Comment: Have you tried `FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath & "\" & FileInFromFolder.Name`?

Comment: VBasic2008's suggestion solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: After investigating the issue, the conclusion is that `FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath & "\"` is sufficient. See the second solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Move All Files

**Microsoft Docs on [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/move-method-filesystemobject-object):**

**Remarks**
*The results of the Move method on a File or Folder **are identical** to operations performed by using FileSystemObject.MoveFile or FileSystemObject.MoveFolder. You should note, however, that the alternative methods are capable of **moving multiple files or folders.***

**Microsoft Docs on [`MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefile-method):**

**Remarks**
*If source contains wildcards **or destination ends with a path separator**, it is assumed that destination specifies an existing folder in which to move the matching files. **Otherwise, destination is assumed to be the name of a destination file to create.** In either case, three things can happen when an individual file is moved:*

- *If destination does not exist, the file gets moved. This is the usual case.*
- *If destination is an existing file, an error occurs.*
- ***If destination is a directory, an error occurs.***

**The Investigation**
**`fso.MoveFile`**

- At first glance it seems like `fso.MoveFile` is the way to go, but it's not so simple.
- The first issue is that if there are no files in source, an error will occur: solved with `If .GetFolder(FromPath).Files.Count > 0 Then`.
- The second (worse) issue is that if a file already exists in destination you cannot be sure what will be copied, before an error occurs: not solved.
- Off course, if you know that destination is empty, or at least there aren't any existing files, this is the more efficient way. But I wouldn't bet on it.
- `FromPath` has to be followed by the `PathSeparator` and at least an `*`, while `ToPath` has to end with the `PathSeparator`.

**`fso.File.Move`**

- The `fso.File.Move` solution has to loop through files. But you don't need to check the files count and you can implement `If Not .FileExists(ToPath & fsoFile.Name) Then` to check the existence of a file with the same name in destination.
- `ToPath` has to end with the `PathSeparator`, but can optionally be followed by the file name (`fsoFile.Name`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub moveAllFilesFSO()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim FromPath As String: FromPath = ws.Range("E1").Value
    Dim ToPath As String: ToPath = ws.Range("E3").Value
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FolderExists(FromPath) And .FolderExists(ToPath) Then
            If .GetFolder(FromPath).Files.Count > 0 Then
                Dim Sep As String: Sep = Application.PathSeparator
                If Right(FromPath, 1) <> Sep Then
                    FromPath = FromPath & Sep
                End If
                FromPath = FromPath & "*" ' "*.*"
                If Right(ToPath, 1) <> Sep Then
                    ToPath = ToPath & Sep
                End If
                .MoveFile FromPath, ToPath
            Else
                Debug.Print "No files found in " & "'" & FromPath & "'."
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "At least one of the folders does not exist."
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub moveAllFilesFile()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim FromPath As String: FromPath = ws.Range("E1").Value
    Dim ToPath As String: ToPath = ws.Range("E3").Value
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FolderExists(FromPath) And .FolderExists(ToPath) Then
            ToPath = .GetFolder(ToPath) & Application.PathSeparator
            Dim fsoFile As Object
            For Each fsoFile In .GetFolder(FromPath).Files
                If Not .FileExists(ToPath & fsoFile.Name) Then
                    fsoFile.Move ToPath ' & fsoFile.Name
                'Else
                    ' File already exists.
                End If
            Next fsoFile
        Else
            Debug.Print "At least one of the folders does not exist."
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```